# Drawing a contour in a specific region of an image and finding the outermost contour in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, hierarchy, contour

My code selects a frame from a video which is than subtracted with a background frame selected from the same video. It is then converted to grayscale, blurred, and then an image threshold is applied. Then a contour is drawn which outputs this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TRNb.png). However, I would only like to have the outermost contour and also not have any contours drawn above y=500. How can I implement this?

Contour code:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tframe,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image = cv2.drawContours(sampleframe, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

I have tried using `cv2.dilate` which works given enough iteration to remove internal contours but the iteration causes the contour to be overestimated which is not desired.

Comment: Use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL rather than cv2.RETR_TREE

Comment: @fmw42 That worked perfectly! Thank you. Just need to figure out how to get rid of the one above ``y=500``

Comment: I am not sure which one, but you can filter on area or perimeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter out the contours by their area size, you can keep the biggest contour. check this link please: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

And for the second problem you can cut your frame on y axis to be lower than 500.

Comment: I managed to sort it by area but this would not always work as the central contour might have an area smaller than that above ```y=500```. How can I cut the frame on the y axis as you have mentioned?

Comment: Just using NumPy slicing like : `tframe = tframe[0:500:, :]` would do the job, note that the origin of the image(i.e. x=0,y=0) is top left of the image.